# How do I know the polarity of the resultant voltage of these two series-connected alternating voltage sources?

Tags: voltage, ac, polarity, phase

I was studying simple vector addition on All About Circuits, and the polarity assigned to the resultant voltage (see picture below) confused me.

Link:

https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/alternating-current/chpt-2/simple-vector-addition/

[image]

when the resultant voltage is taken as 2 V 180 degrees, why is polarity like this? I Understand that the 2 V 0 degrees should have the reverse polarity of the latter but I don't understand why the polarity is assigned like this.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that since the 8 V alternating voltage source is the one with the bigger magnitude, the resulting voltage if written as 2 V 180 degrees, will have its polarity, and vice versa if written as -2 V at 0 degrees.